# How to check if an opened file has been moved or removed by another process

Tags: c, linux

I have a process using C on Linux OS that writes data to a file. It uses `open()`/`write()` functions and I've been wondering if another process `rm`'d or `mv`'d the file. How can my process find out and recreate the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `fstat()` to get the information about the open file.  If the `st_nlink` field is zero, the file has been removed from the file system (possibly by being moved to a different file system, but there's no real way for you to determine that).  There's a decent chance you have the only remaining reference to that file - though there might be other processes also holding it open.  The disk space won't be released until the last process with an open file descriptor for the file finally closes the file.

If the `st_nlink` field is still positive, then your file still has a name somewhere out in the file system.  You then need to use `stat()` to determine whether the `st_dev` and `st_ino` fields for the given file name match the same fields from the file descriptor.  If the name still exists and has the same device and inode number, then it is 'the same' file (though the contents may have changed).  If there's a difference, then the open file is different from the file specified by name.

Note that if you want to be sure that the given name is not a symbolic link to a moved copy of the file, then you would have to use `lstat()` on the file when you open it (to ensure it isn't a symlink at that point), and again when you check the file (instead of using `stat()`).

Comment: +1 I was going to answer this question but you covered everything already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [stat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28Unix%29) call to do this.

```
struct stat st;
if(stat("/tmp",&st) == 0)
        printf(" /tmp is present\n");
else
    /* Write code to create the file */
```

Comment: you'll want to check that the inode hasn't changed - this would indicate the file has been replaced with a different file

Comment: Agreed. But the OP states that he just needs to check if the file has been `mv`'d of `rm`'d, hence my answer

Comment: Yes. The problem is your answer gives a false negative if the file is mv'd or rm'd, then a new (but distinct) file created in its place. Note that the OP says an 'opened file', so you'll want to compre the inode with that from the opened file descriptor

Comment: Thanks @bdonlan.  that's what should be considered/handled.

Comment: "and recreate the file" could run into problems if the thing bdonlan describes has happened. If the current user lacks the permissions needed to get rid of the replacement, then you can't recreate the file.